# Search field and redirect to all routes

Tags: angular

I have all my routes, which I declared in my app-routing.module.ts in an array.
Now I want to have a search-field and when the user clicks on the route, the user is redirected to route. What is the best possible way to do that?

I already tried to do it with the "a" tag and routerLink, when the user clicks on it, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you please provide some code for your described question? There is no general way of building such a thing.
Using `<a>` with `routerLink` should work actually, so the problem might live within the details here.

Comment: Can you clarify your question and also post what you already have tried (code). If I understand correctly, you want a dynamic `routerLink` based on users input?

Comment: You can do programmatic navigation by injecting the Angular `Router` into your component and calling `navigate` or `navigateByUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

because you didn't provide a code i will try to give you a working solution.

the a tag that you are trying to use with router link you should set a slash before the router for example:

```
<a routerLink="/client/add">
  <i>New</i>
</a>
```

While in app.routing.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AddClientComponent } from 'src/app/components/add-client/add-client.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'client/add', component: AddClientComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ]
})
```

it's work fine for me, i hope this solve your issue